# I'm having trouble with a function in php to redirect my application

Tags: php

```
function url(string $path = null): string
{
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], needle: "localhost")) { 
        if ($path) {
            return CONF_URL_TEST . "/" . ($path[0] == "/" ? mb_substr($path, 1) : $path);
        }
        return CONF_URL_TEST;
    }

    if ($path) {
        return CONF_URL_BASE . "/" . ($path[0] == "/" ? mb_substr($path, 1) : $path);
    }
}
```

from what i saw this part of the code is not working

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], needle: "localhost"))

can someone give me a light please

Comment: "is not working" - because you are getting an error or something else?

Comment: Why do you have `needle:` in there? And why is this using `strpos` to begin with, is a simple comparison for equality not enough?

Comment: This doesn't actually redirect anything either. It just, in some cases, returns a URL, which we don't even know is the issue or not. Show some examples what you expect to happen in different situations. Since you say it doesn't work as you want, we can't really assume what you expect. However, the issue is most likely what the answer below mentions. If the HTTP_HOST is "localhost", strpos() will return 0, which is a falsy value.

Answer (score 0):

strpos return an int so it can be `0`. you can use

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],  "localhost") > -1)
```

or

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],  "localhost") !== false)
```

you can check for more : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos